# spring 3 bean configuration files

Tags: spring-3

I've got a small question, just to be sure...

Do I have to store different beans in different files? 
For example: Does the bean, which handles servlet-mapping, have to be in an different file than the one which is dealing with database access?

Answer (score 0):

Spring doesn't impose any rules on how bean definitions are stored in various configuration files. It does provide `<import>` facility so that you can organize bean definitions into more manageable files and import them into your main spring configuration file.